# Multisite wordpress can't auto installed

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, multisite

My study case, i have a domain (ex: website.com) in wordpress platform.

After I use multisite wordpress plugin, I create subdomains (ex: a.website.com, b.website.com, c.website.com) but also that the contents of that subdomain is empty. Can I create a subdomain of a, b, c these can be automatically installed wordpress?

Or, is there another way to solve my problem?

thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the content of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: What do you mean? please explain more about .htaccess
in this case the subdomain has been created but it still empty not wordpress installed, now can be made auto install wordpress?

Comment: Okay, first thing is first. Have you installed WordPress on the root site (e.x. example.com)? If so, how did you enable WordPress Multi-Site? If you used a plugin, can you provide a link to it on the WordPress Plugin Repository (e.x. https://wordpress.org/plugins/xyz). Have you set up your host to allow wildcard domains to this WordPress install? And finally, I need the `.htaccess` root site. If you need help finding it, look (via FTP/SFTP) for the hidden `.htaccess` file in the `webroot` or `public_html` directory.

Comment: ohh if I already know, but how to create subdomains created automatically installed without need to be uploaded manually :)

Comment: You did not answer my question. I can't help you if you don't answer my questions.